# Ursina engine not rendering mesh properly?

Tags: python, rendering, game-development, ursina

i am creating a small game using Ursina and i have code which generates a terrain mesh using perlin noise. the mesh itself renders but i can't put textures on it properly and shaders do not work on it, it just renders as a solid colour.

[screenshot of the game - terrain is all one colour and not shaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn1Uq.jpg)

here's my code

`

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
from ursina.shaders import lit_with_shadows_shader
from perlin_noise import PerlinNoise
import time

game = Ursina()

window.title = "new_game"
window.borderless = False
window.fps_counter.enabled = True
window.exit_button.visible = False
window.fullscreen = False

groundTexture = load_texture("assets/placeholder.png")
crosshairTexture = load_texture("assets/crosshair.png")

crosshair = Entity(model = "cube", texture = crosshairTexture, parent = camera.ui, scale = 0.2)
crosshair.always_on_top = True

title = Text("new game", origin = (6.825, -19))
coordinates = Text("", origin = (3.35, -8))

mode = 1

size = 20
level =  size / 10
seed = random.randint(1, 1000000)
noise = PerlinNoise(octaves = 3, seed = seed)

vertices = [0] * ((size + 1) * (size + 1))

i = 0

for z in range(size + 1):

    for x in range(size + 1):

        y = level * noise([x / size, z / size])

        vertices[i] = x, y, z

        i = i + 1

triangles = [0] * (size * size * 6)

vert = 0
tris = 0

for z in range(size):

    for x in range(size):

        triangles[tris + 0] = vert + 0
        triangles[tris + 1] = vert + size + 1
        triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1
        triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1
        triangles[tris + 4] = vert + size + 1
        triangles[tris + 5] = vert + size + 2

        vert = vert + 1
        tris = tris + 6

    vert = vert + 1

triangles.reverse() # array is made counter-clockwise

def input(key):

    if key == "escape":
        
        Audio(sound_file_name = "assets/tick.wav")

        time.sleep(0.25)

        exit()

def update():

    coordinates.text = "coordinates (x, y, z):\n" + str(player.position)

# MAIN

terrainMesh = Mesh(vertices, triangles)

terrain = Entity(model = terrainMesh, collider = "mesh", texture = "grass_big", shader = lit_with_shadows_shader)

box = Entity(model = "cube", collider = "mesh", texture = "white_cube", position = (10, 5, 10), shader = lit_with_shadows_shader)

pivot = Entity()
DirectionalLight(parent=pivot, x = 10, y = 10, z = 15, shadows = True, rotation = (45, -45, 45))

if mode == 1:
    
    player = FirstPersonController()

if mode == 2:

    player = EditorCamera()

player.position = (10, 5, 10)
    
game.run()
```

`

i have tried looking into how to normalise the mesh or use shaders with it but there is practically no helpful documentation on it whatsoever. i wrote the code that generates the mesh but i don't know enough about shaders and normalisation to fix the issue myself. i was wondering if there's a built in function that does this? (i have tried a few and i didn't know how to use them/they didn't work) any help is much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

How should the texture map to the model? You have to define this by giving it uvs.

> UVs are two-dimensional texture coordinates that correspond with the
> vertex information for your geometry. UVs are vital because they
> provide the link between a surface mesh and how an image texture gets
> applied onto that surface. They are basically marker points that
> control which pixels on the texture correspond to which vertex on the
> 3D mesh.
> https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/film-games/understanding-uvs-love-them-or-hate-them-theyre-essential-to-know

To do this with ursina, give the Mesh a list of two dimensional coordinates, one Vec2 for each vertex.